# What's the difference between Data Race and Condition in Go?

Tags: go

Hi i'm new in go and i currently still learning on it, there is a question about the difference between data race and race condition, i get a bit confused about the difference between it and can someone tell me what is the real different between those condition and the sample answer ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

A data race is a kind of race condition.

A data race is where a variable is written concurrently with other reads and writes of the variable.  Here's a data race example:

```
 x := 1
 go func() { x = 2 }()  // The write to x on this line executes ...
 fmt.Println(x)         // concurrently with the read on this line
```

The program can print 1, 2, or fail in some unspecified way.

A race condition is where concurrently executing code produces different results due to nondeterministic timing. Here's a race condition example (that is not a data race):

```
 ch := make(chan int, 1)
 go func() { ch <- 1 }()
 go func() { ch <- 2 }()
 fmt.Println(<-ch)
```

The goroutines race to send a value to the channel. The program can print 1 or 2.

Comment: "What do we want?" "NOW!" "When do we want it?" "FEWER RACE CONDITIONS!"

Comment: The "different results due to nondeterministic timing" often are unproblematic if both results are valid. The colloquial use of "race condition" IMHO implies that only some of the possible outcomes are correct and the others are bugs.